# I added jar files in Python folder site packages and Couldn't see the imported Libraries in IDE while running

Tags: python, robotframework

[image: <code>Am getting the following error while executing running the robot file</code>]

**While Running the robot file and getting the below error. Can someone help me where to add the jar files exactly**

> [ ERROR ] Error in file '/Users/ts-admin/Downloads/robotframework-jmslibrary-master/src/test/robotframework/acceptance/connection.txt': Importing test library 'JMSLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named JMSLibrary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix Python and Java like the way you have described above.

You have to use Jython instead.

Go through the below link for more information.

[Using physical path to library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id564)

Answer (score 0):

Try importing libraries with .py format into a .robot file
If you want to use .jar libraries you will need to use Java-Selenium